# Where is the headless-chrome settings file?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to font setting on headless-chrome.
Where is the headless-chrome settings file?

`~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences` is not exist

Answer (score 2):

This problem is raised in
[Issue 1925: Expose content settings in headless mode](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1925),
from Aug 10, 2017, where the answer by the developers is:

> Headless does not include large chunks of Chromium. Preference
>   handling is one of them. Including it would be a moderately large
>   task, so I don't think it will be happening soon, at least not by the
>   Google team working on headless. If someone else does it, naturally
>   we'll be happy to review patches.
>
> This is really a feature request rather than a bug.
>
> I'm unassigning this for now. If it gets enough stars we'll put it on
>   our roadmap.

When users complained, another developer added:

> The content settings are a chrome/ layer feature. Getting this to work in headless mode would be a large project, which isn't currently planned.  Sorry.

I'm afraid that you are out of luck : Headless does not support preference handling
and this feature is not currently planned.